# PHP spreadsheet writer writing variables to excel

Tags: php, excel, file-io

I am trying to write variables from an array to the excel but i cannot write in certain instances

Code is as below

```
$workbook =new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();
$workbook->send("response.xls");
$row=1;
$col=1;
$workbook->setVersion(8);
$worksheet =& $workbook->addWorksheet('My sheet ');
$Allquestions = $questions->getQuestions();
foreach ($Allquestions as $qkey=>$qval) {
    foreach ($studentResponses as $rval){
        $astresp= $rval->getResponse($qkey);
        //$worksheet->write($row,$col,'hiii');
        $worksheet->write($row, $col, $astresp);
        $col++;
    }
    $row++;
    $col=1;
}
$workbook->close();
```

the $astresp when changed to 'hihi' prints hihi in the excel but when it remains as $astresp it fails to open excel.

Comment: Have you done a var_dump($astresp); to see if there is actually anything in it?

Comment: Yes.. I have text in it.. when i do an echo i can see the text in that variable

Comment: Don't echo, use var_dump() instead. It may be that $astresp is an object rather than a string

Comment: This is the output in html when i do var dump --> 

string 'S�t�r�o�n�g�l�y� �a�g�r�e�e�' (length=28)  --> end

Comment: So what charset is that?

Comment: I havent set any char set .. so it must be default! This is what i found in php.ini default_charset = "iso-8859-1" .. I am reading from an excel and writing to a new excel. The $astresp is read from an excel

Comment: What library are you using to read from the first Excel file? You should be able to identify the charset from that

Comment: $astresp = iconv('UTF-16LE',$data->_defaultEncoding , $astresp);

-> I used the above line and vardump gives me proper text as string 'strongly agree' but i am unable to still write to excel

Comment: Convert it to UTF-8 rather than $data->_defaultEncoding (unless $data->_defaultEncoding is set to UTF-8)

Comment: /me is still trying to figure out why you're reading from one Excel workbook using one library, and writing to a different Excel workbook using a different library

Comment: I gave up, i was using the extension by pear and moved to use PHPExcel. Its fixed now :) thanks